# onscroll function, if child got a class then add a class for parent also

Tags: jquery, html, css

on window scroll when p element got a class then add another class to his parent tag.

In the "**second section**" The jQuery code I write, in this way can I check the "p" tags class status and add class to his parent "div"?

I do not want to write any other code in **first section**.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    
    // first section
    if (scroll >= 300) {
        $("p").addClass("bgwhite");
    } else {
      $("p").removeClass("bgwhite");
    }
    
    // second section
    if( $("p").hasClass("bgwhite")){
      $(this).parent().addClass("headerGreen");
    }
    
    
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  color:#fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  min-height:1000px;
}

div {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.bgwhite {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #20262E;
}

.headerGreen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `this` in `$(this).parent().addClass("headerGreen");` to `"p"` I believe it gives the desired result.